# SQL create a dynamic sequential number in a select statement based on a SortOrder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sequential-number

I want to generate a new column with a sequential number based on a data column `SortOrder`.

The `Sortorder` is returned from a subquery, where I manually mapped floor designations of buildings.

| Building | Floor | SortOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BuildingA | 1. floor | 3 |
| BuildingA | rooftop | 11 |
| BuildingA | ground | 0 |
| BuildingB | Ground | 0 |
| BuildingB | rooftop | 11 |
| BuildingB | secondfloor | 4 |

This is my current query. Now I want a new column that looks like that

| Building | Floor | SortOrder | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BuildingA | 1. floor | 3 | 2 |
| BuildingA | rooftop | 11 | 3 |
| BuildingA | ground | 0 | 1 |
| BuildingB | Ground | 0 | 1 |
| BuildingB | rooftop | 11 | 3 |
| BuildingB | secondfloor | 4 | 2 |

The query needs to group the buildings by their names, orders them by Sort order and create based on that a sequential number.

I tried messing around with `ROW_NUMBER OVER` by joining a subquery with a group by, but that did not work out.

Comment: *"This is my current querry"* Where? You didn't include it.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Building ORDER BY SortOrder) AS Counter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANK() or DENSE_RANK() based on what you need, as I don't have clarity more about your data I"m going with RANK() in my solution.

```
with cte as (

select 'BuildingA' as Building, '1.floor'    as Floor ,3 as SortOrder
union all
select 'BuildingA' as Building, 'rooftop'    as Floor ,11 as SortOrder
union all
select 'BuildingA' as Building, 'ground'     as Floor ,0 as SortOrder
union all
select 'BuildingB' as Building, 'Ground'     as Floor ,0 as SortOrder
union all
select 'BuildingB' as Building, 'rooftop'    as Floor ,11 as SortOrder
union all
select 'BuildingB' as Building, 'secondfloor'    as Floor ,4 as SortOrder
)

select *, RANK() over(partition by building order by sortorder ) as Counter from cte
```

With this you get your desired output.

Comment: if you use `row_number()` it will also give the same result

Comment: Yes, it will give same result.

Comment: No `ROW_NUMBER` is more correct, as `RANK` will give different results if there are ties

Comment: Yes, but as per my understanding of data, if we have ties based on the floor then it makes more same to assign them the same counter if they belong to the same building and floor. Based, on this assumption I used RANK(), but yes, if this assumption is wrong then we can use row_number(). I have edited my answer